# How to create gz zip file from byte array which is generated from gziptream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have .net core application in which i am creating in memory zip with three file and sending it in byte array to another client application.
Now I am struggling in my client application to save this byte array into .gz zip file.
My code for creating Archive is

```
byte[] fileBytes = null;
 using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // create a zip
                using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    // iterate through the source files
                    foreach (var f in obj.CsvDictionary)
                    {
                        // add the item name to the zip
                        ZipArchiveEntry zipItem = zip.CreateEntry(f.Key);//f.key contains file name
                        // add the item bytes to the zip entry by opening the original file and copying the bytes 
                        using (var originalFileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(f.Value.ToString())))//f.value contains file contents
                        {
                            using (var entryStream = zipItem.Open())
                            {
                                originalFileMemoryStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: this question is marked for close with reason as this is not looks like a programming problem. just pathetic thinking. people here are now mostly target to buy easy points rather then answering the tech question.

Comment: Don't care much about negative marking. i am sure it will help someone else as well even it cost me negative points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Temp\Myfile.zip", myrequestarray);
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/666195/Byte-Array-to-Zip-File

Comment: So the actual question was `How can I save a byte array to disk`? That's why this question was downvoted - the title and code aren't relevant, there's no description of the problem and no indication that there was an attempt to solve or investigate the problem.